# How can I rotate the writing. my pdf is a template in landscape mode with itext

Tags: java, itext, landscape

I have searched many forums but nothing has solved my problem

here is my code
Thanks in advance

@WebServlet("/pdfexport")
public class PDFExport extends HttpServlet {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3946473150566453971L;


@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


           String masterPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/Bulletin.pdf");

            response.setContentType("application/pdf"); 

    try (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(masterPath);
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(response.getOutputStream());

            PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);)

    {   

        PdfPage page = document.getPage(1);
        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);

        FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont();
        PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontProgram, "utf-8", true);
        canvas.setFontAndSize(font,8);

        canvas.beginText();
        canvas.setTextMatrix(100, 100);
        canvas.showText("test");

        canvas.setTextMatrix(200, 200);
        canvas.showText("test");




        canvas.endText();
    }

}
```

}

And my pdf in landscape format

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something: itext has all its API documentation online, surely there is a function on the pdf document to set the page orientation.

Comment: You use the `canvas.setTextMatrix` overload with two parameters. Use an overload instead with six numeric parameters to set the whole matrix, or use an overload which accepts an `AffineTransformation`.